# Can we use Leanback library (video player widgets)for Android Mobile App?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-appwidget, android-tv, leanback

I am a newbie to Android TV app development.
I want to develop a app for both TV and Mobile. When I imported a sample TV application, I found a leanback widget for video player ( with play, pause buttons). Can I use the same leanback widget in the mobile app too? If not please let me know the limitations. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing preventing you from adding the [Leanback Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v17-leanback) to your project, but it probably wouldn't be a good idea to create a single module for both a mobile and TV application.

The widgets provided by the Leanback Library are optimized for large screens and using a remote control. On the other hand, widgets provided by the core framework and the [Design Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#design) are optimized for smaller screens and touch controls. Therefore, the Leanback Library widgets would likely appear much too large, busy or otherwise unfit on a mobile device.

The core framework does provide the [`MediaController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html) view, which is similar to the [`PlaybackOverlayFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/PlaybackOverlayFragment.html) (or more specifically, the [`PlaybackControlsRow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/PlaybackControlsRow.html)) provided by the Leanback Library, but designed with smaller screens in mind.